# Using difference of pointers with printf("%.*s")

Tags: c, pointers, integer, printf, format-specifiers

The problem I'm facing has to do with `intptr_t` data type and the way `fprintf()` takes arguments for the `%.*s` format. The `%.*s` format expect field precision to have type `int`, and maybe that's not unreasonable per se.

Not in this case though:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    char fname[] = "Some_File.txt";
    FILE *write = fopen(fname, "w");
    
    if (write != NULL) {

        printf("\n\tType below :\n\n");
        char in[501] = ""; char *p;

        while (1) {
            fgets(in, MAX_LN, stdin);

    /*** Region with compiler warnings begins ***/
            if ((p = strstr(in, "/end/")) != 0) {
                intptr_t o = p - in;
                fprintf(write, "%.*s", o, in);
    /*** Region with compiler warnings ends ***/
                fclose(write);
                break;
            } else {
                fputs(in, write);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- If I compile this, it doesn't play well with `%.*s`, and the compiler points that out:

  > warning: field precision should have type 'int', but argument has type 'intptr_t' (aka 'long') [-Wformat]
- If I make it `int o;`, it plays well with `%.*s` but of course isn't ideal, and the compiler says as much:

  > warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]

Now, this is demo code, and the max size that `o` can hold is `500` here, however, in my actual code, it can be `10,000` or even `100,000` (still very much within the size of a 32-bit int, isn't it?)

So what will resolve this *best* with the *least* changes?

Compiled on Clang (might be very similar on GCC) with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: `intptr_t o; = p-in;` is a syntax error, so how far is this potentially from the real code?

Comment: @Ry- It's a snippet from real code with a small `Ctrl`-`C` & `Ctrl`-`V` mistake The real code declares the variables above these statements, so it isn't an issue there ! (I've corrected it here, thanks)

Comment: Couldn't you just do `*p = 0;` and just use `%s`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Terminate the string at the delimiter and then just print it. You could even use `fputs` if you prefer.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm using that here , and it is quite brilliant .However, in another place, I cannot terminate or overwrite my string (where I'm replacing phrases in a line) , which is the type of place where this may not be good though. However, as far as the code in-question is concerned , this is a viable solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference of two pointers is type `ptrdiff_t`.  "... is the signed integer type of the result of subtracting two pointers;"

```
// intptr_t o = p-in;
ptrdiff_t o = p - in;
```

Given these both point in `char in[501]`, the difference also fits in an `int`.
Simply cast.  The `.*` expects a match `int`, not a `intptr_t` nor `ptrdiff_t`.

```
// fprintf(write,"%.*s",o,in);
fprintf(write,"%.*s", (int) o, in);
```

Or all at once:

```
fprintf(write,"%.*s", (int) (p - in), in);
```

Comment: What does the standard say about the size of `int` ? The real code uses a string of size `10,000` , so this should fit into an int portably, right ?

Comment: @user13863346 Per C spec, `int` has _at least_ the range of [-32767...32767] and commonly today is 4-byte with a range of +/- (2^31 - 1).  Code using `printf()` or `fwrite()` as suggested elsewhere.  Best to use whatever  makes your code easiest to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The type of a pointer difference such as `p-in` is `ptrdiff_t`, not `intptr_t`. Anyway, one alternative in this case would be to use `fwrite`:

```c
if ((p = strstr(in, "/end/")) != NULL) {
    size_t len = (size_t)(p - in);  // p - in is an offset into data with a size
    fwrite(in, sizeof(char), len, write);
    fclose(write);
    break;
} else {
    fputs(in, write);
}
```

Then add error checks.

Comment: Hmm... so using `printf()` isn't a good idea ?

Comment: @user13863346: I’d say `fprintf` with `%.*s` in general isn’t good idea here, yeah, but especially not when it’s the entire format string. Then there’s no reason not to use `fwrite`.

Comment: the difference is ptrdiff_t, never size_t which is an unsigned type!! and the 2 need not even be of same width

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: In this case it’s known that the result is a size.